# Gulp + JS libraries + JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, gulp

I have a single-page webapp, for which I'm using various external JS files:

- libraries found via `bower`
- other libraries not shipped as `bower` packages (i.e. some other js scripts i have locally)
- A JSON file with some data
- My `main.js` file that integrates all the JS code

Now, I'm trying to wrap my head around the best way to build and ship the JS component of such app.

Normally I would just call such files via the `<script></script>` tag in the `index.html`, but in Gulp I'm kinda lost on what could actually be the best way.

Should I bundle every JS file in a single file PLUS the JSON?

If not, what is the best way to include a JSON file via gulp?

Comment: Glup is just a tool to automate your workflow. If you should  concat all your js files to one file or just certain ones, is up to you and depends on your use case.

Comment: Right I'm sorry I wrote poorly the question. Now I've edited it. I meant: Should I include ALSO the JSON in the bundle with all other js files? Is that a good practice?

Comment: What is the JSON for?  Configuration of your app, temp stubbed data for REST services, etc.?

Comment: Data for a script ( some markers on a web-map).

Comment: If you data is static then it might be a good idea to include it with your script because this save one additional request. If that data is large and you won't need it all the time then it might be a bad idea to include it.

Comment: Right, but then, how to minify/concat it? Using the same gulp plugins I'm using for regular JS scripts (i.e. uglify, jshint..) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking the right questions, but gulp by itself doesn't solve your problems (just gives you the tool to do so). What you're looking for is a module system. The two most common styles of modules are [AMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) and [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS).

For example, if you were using [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/), you would have a single script file that is considered the *entry* point (which is the single script that is loaded via `<script src='/js/entry.build.js'>`.

Your `entry.js` might look something like this before being 'built':

```
var $ = require('bower_components/jQuery');
var jsonData = require('js/json-data.js');

$(function() {
   // do something with jsonData
})
```

And after running Webpack on entry.js, it will output a js file that has all the dependancies bundled into it.

You may also want to look into [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) for similar functionality.

Comment: thanks Jonathan Dumaine, as I said in a previous comment Browserify looks like a good combination. I'll try to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Is it possible to use Browserify inside Gulp?

Answer (score 0):

If you data is static then it might be a good idea to include it with your script because this save one additional request. If that data is large and you won't need it all the time then it might be a bad idea to include it.

For that case the data is static and used all the time you could do something like this, but be award that this is just to illustrate how you could do it but this is not a good code):

**datastorage.js**

```
/*
  some simple data storage with a defined interface to register and retrive data 
*/
var dataStorage = {};

function registerData(key, value) {
  dataStorage[key] = value;
}

function data(key) {
  return dataStorage[key];
}
```

**data1.js**

```
registerData('data1', {
    "propertyA" : "valueA"
    /* some more data */
});
```

**main.js**

```
/**  a part of your code where you access this data **/
console.log(data('data1').propertyA);
```

You should look a AMD, RequireJS, CommonJS,  ES Harmony before you start implementing a data storage, to use a common technique of loading/registering data.

Comment: thanks @t.niese for your answer. I'm gonna study more in depth CommonJS and Browserify.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same headache of bundling different things. I did some research and figured out a way to bundle everything into a single html page. Including images and fonts. It also minifies and optimizes every file.  So your whole single page app can really be in a single html page. All you have to do is pass in the start page (Ex. Index.html) I just published my project on Git Hub and nugget  its called SPAFramework/SpaBundler you can try it and also help further develop it as it is really just a working rough draft.